# how to get the name of a user by uid in erlang?

Tags: erlang

The **[File](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/file.html) module** has function such as File:file_info() and File:read_file_info that return the [**#file_info**](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/file.html#type-file_info) record relative to a file. It contains fields such as **uid** and **gid** that are **numeric identifiers** that relate to the OS user id and group id.

All file operations use the numeric uid and gid values, but it would be nice to identify it by user name (string), considering the uid on a host might be different than another host, but the user name might be the same by matters of department convention (installation policy/etc).

**Question:** Is there  a module or function that works on most operating systems to retrieve the user name and group name for a given uid or gid ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `C` function of choice is `getpwuid` for POSIX-compliant operating systems. To get the group name, the equivalent is `getgrgid`.

Jungerl used to have a `posix_drv` [driver module](https://github.com/gebi/jungerl/blob/master/lib/posix_drv/README) that provided both, among other things. 
But it's pretty old and hasn't survived the changes in R15 that affect driver APIs.

An alternative might be this: https://github.com/sergey-miryanov/erlang-pwd - gives you a `get_by_uid` (that calls `getpwuid`) but does not have an equivalent to `getgrgid`.